# Nuxt parallel build option causes not found warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm trying to optimize a Nuxt app and I ran into some problems with the 'parallel' option of build in nuxt.config.js.

My understanding is that this uses [thread-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/thread-loader#thread-loader). I have tried reinstalling the latest version of thread-loader and its dependencies but this didn't resolve the issue.

I get the following error during the build when I set `parallel: true`

> ./layouts/default.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:290-293
>   "export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-0!../node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-1!../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-2!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./default.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&'

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your build target doesn't force exports as ES modules but instead exports `module.default`. So either re-write the code so that it transpiles down correctly to your environment, or change the target to `esnext` or `es2017` at the very least.

Comment: How does this relate to the parallel option? I mean why does it show a warning with `parallel: true` but no warning with `parallel:false` ?

Comment: That's a fantastic question. The `parallel` option likely requires vendors that export with `module.exports...` as opposed to `export default {}` and your build target is likely `es2015`, hence why you get that error. The `export 'default' (imported as 'X')` error is ambiguous, but related to the aforementioned.

Comment: That is definitely possible. But it looks like the problem wasn't in my own build target, since it was already set to `esnext`. It turns out that the version for thread-loader was set to an outdated version in package.json. Forcing an upgrade to 2.1.3 solved it.